# I am unable to use MySQL due to a "refused connection"

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run the no-install version of MySQL on Windows XP located in *C:/mysql/* on my machine.

The error message I receive within a PHP file when I try to connect to MySQL reads.

> Could not connect: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I have edited the config file *my.ini* and altered/added the following.

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = C:/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = C:/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
basedir = C:/mysql/
datadir = C:/mysql/data/
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
skip-networking
enable-named-pipe
```

When I run mysqld.exe I can confirm it is running within command prompt tasklist.
However when I try cmd *netstat -a* I cannot see any port usage at 3306.

Inside MySQL error logs, it reads.

> 140411 13:30:34 [Note] c:\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
>   Version: '5.5.37-log'  socket: ''  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

The port: 0 doesn't look correct to me, but I am not sure.

When I run mysql.exe direct in cmd I get the following returned

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

Some things I have tried already.

- Placing a copy of *my.ini* in C:/WINDOWS and also a copy within C:/mysql
- Changing *bind-address = 127.0.0.1* to *bind-address =
  localhost*
- Inside PHP file MySQL connection variants, *localhost*, *127.0.0.1*, *127.0.0.1:3306* inside basic mysql_connect()
- Created tmp/mysql.sock file (in case dir + file not existing matters)
- Commented out *skip-networking* in *my.ini*
- After running mysqld.exe whilst running ran mysqladmin.exe in cmd which returns 'Can't connect to MySQL server at 'localhost'
- Running telnet localhost 3306 returns 
  '*Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: C
  onnect failed*'
- Commented out *bind-address* in *my.ini* to allow default settings.
- Ran mysqld.exe with user root (*-u root*) also inserted *user = root* in *my.ini*
- Set Windows Firewall to off.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What command are you using to connect? If you are connecting to 127.0.0.1 instead of `localhost`, it will use TCP instead of the socket, but you have `skip-networking` so it will fail.

Comment: What does your PHP code look like? You may have the wrong connection string.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski and user2254180 I have updated my list of what I have tried, I should of included these originally as I already tried many php mysql connection variants.

Comment: @cecilli0n Have you read this [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_enable-named-pipe). Named pipes works only with mysqld-nt and you are running mysqld. You need named pipes for skip networking

Comment: Make sure you can connect from the console i.e. `mysql -h localhost dbname`.

Comment: Agree with @halfer - don't involve PHP code until you know how to connect to the service from a plain client. Seems like you most likely need to comment out `skip-networking` though...

Comment: @Soyale and Berokwski I have commented out skip-networking but still doesn't work, Updated tried list. halfer When I run that command with mysql.exe I see alot of text scroll and the cmd closes(mysql.exe doesn't appear in tasklist after) EDIT: When  I run only mysql.exe in console I am getting "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to mysql on server 'localhost' (10061)"

Comment: If you see a lot of text scroll, edit it into to your question. You can probably redirect it to a file with `mysql -h localhost dbname > output.txt` too, to make it easier.

Comment: @halfer it seems the textscroll was just help information about version/options/licensing etc. I have updated the main post with the error a basic mysql.exe error returns, I am researching google/stack for this error.

Comment: @cecilli0n Ok. You have binded your server to specific ip so please read this [MySQL bind-addres](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address). Please unbind your server and check if you have proper user. (last paragraph in documentation)

Comment: @Soyale I have commented out bind-address so the default should use used. When starting mysqld.exe I supplied -u root, it runs and I can also see it via tasklist, but trying to start mysql.exe whilst this is running still shows same error. I have updated my tried list with more info.

Comment: I am checking documentation for tmp/mysql.sock as this is one of the last options which I have edited since fresh download from MySQL.

Comment: I have got some type of connection, need to undo my last 2-4 edits to find which allowed mysql.exe to run successfully.

Comment: @Soyale I believe it was the bind-address option that was causing the problem, it seemed that commenting this out allowed the connection to be made, regardless of the user info. If you put this in a answer post I will click accepted. Thanks also to everybody who provided earlier information which also contributed to the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. You have binded your server to specific ip so please read this [MySQL bind-addres](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address). Please unbind your server and check if you have proper user. (last paragraph in documentation)